# $('body, html').is(':animated')) doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 divs with heights set to window height. I want on each scroll down to scroll to the next one, however after the first scroll down it just keeps on scrolling, seemingly ignoring `is:animated`

```
<style>

    .div {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .red {
        background: red;
    }

    .yellow {
        background: yellow;
    }

    .green {
        background: green;
    }

    .blue {
        background: blue;
    }

</style>

<div id="id0" data-id="0" class="nbhd red scrolledto"></div>
<div id="id1" data-id="1" class="nbhd yellow"></div>
<div id="id2" data-id="2" class="nbhd green"></div>
<div id="id3" data-id="3" class="nbhd blue"></div>



function setHeights() {
        $('.nbhd').css('height', window.innerHeight);
    }

    function scrollSections() {

        if ($('body, html').is(':animated')) {
            return;
        }

        var currentSectionId = $('.nbhd.scrolledto').data('id');

        currentSectionId++;

        $('.scrolledto').removeClass('scrolledto');

        var section = $('#id'+currentSectionId);

        section.addClass('scrolledto');

        var pos = section.offset().top;

        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000, function() {
            console.log('animated');
        });

    }

    setHeights();



    $( window ).on( "scroll", function() {
        scrollSections();
    });
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2d47k6af/

I also get `animated` logged 6 times for some reason, I expected 3.

Comment: You have `animated` logged 6 times because it is logged 3 times for `body`, and 3 times for `html`

Comment: Oh, thanks for that.

Comment: You can use a global variable for resolve your problem : define `var isAnimated = false;` at the top of the script ; Set it to true when `$(window).on('scroll')` ; And reset it to false at the callback of `$('html, body').animate()`

Comment: Doesn't work, if I do that it never even fires in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use variable to achieve, what you want:

```js
function setHeights() {
  $('.nbhd').css('height', window.innerHeight);
}


var isAnimated = false; // Initialize variable
function scrollSections() {
  if (isAnimated) return; // Previous animation still in action
  isAnimated = true; // lock it
  var currentSectionId = $('.nbhd.scrolledto').data('id');

  currentSectionId++;
  var section = $('#id'+currentSectionId);
  if (!section.length) {
    currentSectionId = 0;
    section = $('#id0');
  }

  $('.scrolledto').removeClass('scrolledto');

  section.addClass('scrolledto');

  var pos = section.offset().top;

  $('body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000, function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        isAnimated = false; // unlock it on next eventloop tick
      })
  });
}

setHeights();



$( window ).on( "scroll", function() {
    scrollSections();
});
```

```css
.div {width: 100%;}
.red {background: red;}
.yellow {background: yellow;}
.green {background: green;}
.blue {background: blue;}
```

```html
<div id="id0" data-id="0" class="nbhd red scrolledto"></div>
<div id="id1" data-id="1" class="nbhd yellow"></div>
<div id="id2" data-id="2" class="nbhd green"></div>
<div id="id3" data-id="3" class="nbhd blue"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what you're going for: https://jsfiddle.net/2d47k6af/5/

The problem was that you can't [distinguish scroll events triggered by JavaScript and by user themself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035896/detect-whether-scroll-event-was-created-by-user). So when you run the animation it fired many `$(window).on("scroll", ...);` events that were ignored thanks to `$('body, html').is(':animated')` that worked as expected.

However the last scroll event occured probably after the animation has ended so function `scrollSections()` was called one more time which triggered another animation and so on. My solution would be to add a short timeout after the animation has ended and before it's ready to another user triggered scroll:

```
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000, function() {
  console.log('animated');
  ignoreScrollEvents = true;

  setTimeout(function() {
    ignoreScrollEvents = false;
  }, 100);

});
```